# zshrc custom list does not work

Tags: zsh

I installed zsh to replace bash.

When I configure some custom list in `~/.zshrc`, like

```
source /home/stu/AGV/Mini-PC/ViJie_AGV/devel/setup.zsh
```

and then open a new terminal, it doesn't work. I get this:

```
% roscd teb_local_planner/ 
error: roscd: No such package 'teb_local_planner/'
```

If I source the setup file, it will work.

[image: terminal screenshot]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the details of `roscd`, but `teb_local_planner` looks like a relative path to me. You might need to make it an absolute path, or set a base directory for `roscd`, or something along those lines.

Comment: Can you please show us the addition you made to your zshrc, or preferably the entire file?